# Qt.DecorationRole не показывает изображение

Tags: qt, python-3.x

```
self.icon = 'ico.png'
item = QTableWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon(self.icon), "")
    item.setData(Qt.DecorationRole, item)
    self.table_widget.setItem(0, 0, item)
```

А когда оборачиваю в DisplayRole то показывает, но мне нужно именно в DecorationRole что бы потом сохранить.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `item.setData(Qt.DecorationRole, item)` на `item.setData(Qt.DecorationRole, QtGui.QIcon(self.icon))`

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum):

- `Qt.DisplayRole` требует, чтобы передаваемый объект был приводим к типу `QString` (строке).
- `Qt.DecorationRole` требует, чтобы передаваемый объект был приводим к одному из трёх следующих типов: `QColor` (цвету), `QIcon` (иконке), `QPixmap` (изображению).

**Проблема** заключается в том, что `QTableWidgetItem` приводим *только к строке*. Как результат, элемент-обёртка возвращает для `setData()` пустую строку вместо изображения.

Для **решения** данной проблемы необходимо убрать обёртку над экземпляром `QIcon` и передавать изображение непосредственно:

```
self.icon = 'ico.png'
item = QTableWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon(self.icon), "")
    item.setData(Qt.DecorationRole, QtGui.QIcon(self.icon))
    self.table_widget.setItem(0, 0, item)
```